# ArcGIS FeatureLayer Query not running when using not equals (!=) operator

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I am using the ArcGIS REST Services Directory to run a query on my FeatureLayer and I'm having some trouble. In the documentation it says that the `Where` clause can take `=` and `!=`. The `=` works just fine and it returns the expected values, but the `!=` is saying `Unable to complete operation`. Here is what I'm doing:

[image]

This works just fine, however this doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Arc and even then I may be off, but did you try "<>" instead of "!="?

Comment: No I haven't, although it is one of the options but it doesn't say what it's suppose to do.

Comment: It's another way of saying "not equal". I think one is for numbers and one is for strings/factors. I don't remember which is which.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to be working, greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: The documentation doesn't say `!=` is supported by every data source, it simply says that `!=` is supported within the API because it may be supported by some data sources used in a feature service.  Even if a data source supports using `!=`, it won't be supported if standardized queries are set on the server.  Overall, `<>` is part of the SQL-92 standard and will work all of the time whereas `!=` will work some of the time depending on ArcGIS Server configuration and back-end data source.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.